# Is there any way to do terminal-like interaction with a pair of linux named pipes?

Tags: linux, named-pipes, pty, terminal-emulator

There are two linux named pipes, e.g. `/tmp/test.in` and `/tmp/test.out`.
The named pipes are used by QEMU like `qemu-system-x86_64 -serial pipe:/tmp/test`, so the `test.out` is linux terminal output, and the `test.in` is the input.
I can now open two terminals. When using `ls -l > /tmp/test.in` in one terminal, `cat /tmp/test.out` in another terminal will show the result. However, the experience is not very "terminally".
So, is there a way to use some terminal emulators, like Minicom/GNU screen/Kconsole, (maybe with some shell magic/open source code) to somehow connect to this pair of linux named pipes?

I am currently using a poor python script to scan the output file and read the stdin and write to input file. I think it's not that elegant.